# Proper way for handling ssh keys to clone private repos

Tags: git, jenkins

Since currently our builds require cloning dependencies from private repositories, how could I achieve cloning private repositories using Declarative /Scripted pipeline correctly ?

```
def test_cloning() {
    sshagent(["${SSH_KEY}"]) {
        sh """
            GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" \
            git clone -b dev git@github.com:/org/repo_eg.git repo_eg/
        """

    }    
}

pipeline {
    agent none

    environment {
        SSH_KEY='sshkey'
    }        
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            parallel {
                stage('static_agent') {
                    agent { label 'agent-1 }
                    steps {
                        test_cloning()
                    }
                }
                stage('static_agent') {
                    agent { label 'agent-2' }
                    steps {
                        test_cloning()
                    }
                }
                stage('swarm') {
                    agent { label 'swarm' }
                    steps {
                        sh 'mkdir ~/.ssh || true && ssh-keyscan github.com > ~/.ssh/known_hosts'
                        test_cloning()
                    }
                }                
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            node('agent-1') {
                deleteDir()
            }
            node('agent-2') {
                deleteDir()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hoping this is what you are looking for. Create a private/ public key pair logged in as 'jenkins' user on Jenkins server. Setup Git user's profile (who has access to private repos) with the public key. Add private key to the ssh-agent on Jenkins server.

Use SCM checkout in pipeline script to clone the repo using SSH url

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/

Bitbucket repo example:

```
checkout poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 
"refs/heads/${branchName}"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: 
[], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url:"git@bitbucket.org:${repoName}.git"]]]
```